# Seeing the future

Tags: time

Is it possible to distort time without a  black hole and see all, in one instant, see everything all at once, future, past and present?

And if it was possible to see the future, how would it really work?

By the law of chaos, anything is unpredictable, so a future does not exist at all. But we, now in our present are the future of the past, if people from the past could see the future they would see us. Would they?

Comment: I, uh... Don't understand what you want to know exactly. You should focus your question on a single topic I guess, detailing what you want to know and putting a basic context to help you in building your world. E;g : I have a technology that can send data about the future, present and past at the same time, would someone be able to see all of them at once? It's just an example among many others. I can't know what you wish to know nor do I see the future of this question (:p), so adapt this example for yourself.

Comment: I agree. The posting is so broad that any attempt to respond to it would be certain to be off the mark. In my experience, effective world building comes out of the writer's need to support some aspect of plot, theme, or characterization. But I am unable to detect any such need in this posting.

Comment: Hello NineInchNails. This doesn't appear to be a woldbuilding question. It appears to be a [physics.se] question that's musing on how space-time works. Note that I don't know what "laws of chaos" you're referring to (probably [chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory), but that's more about finding predictability in chaos), but a great deal of our universe is very predictable (thank goodness!). The simplest answer to your question is, no, in real life, you can't see the future. I'm voting to close until we help you work out what you're really asking and why.